# Find a sequence of dependent vertices in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

$Path(v_x, v_y)$ is true if in a graph $G = (V, E)$, $v_x, v_y \in V$ and there exists a path between $v_x$ and $v_y$.

Given a directed graph $G = (V, E)$ with $N$ vertices, find all sequences $(v_1, ..., v_i, ..., v_{j}, ..., v_N)$ consisting of all vertices, for which the followings statement is true:
$ Path(v_i, v_j) \vee ( \exists v_b, v_e : Path(v_b, v_i) \wedge Path(v_b, v_j) \wedge Path(v_i, v_e) \wedge Path(v_j, v_e) )$

Does this happen to be a known problem that you recognise?

Example: Take $G$ where the edge set is $E = \{ab, ac, bd, cd\}$. There are only two possible sequences which are $(a,b,c,d)$ and $(a,c,b,d)$